# How do I send notifications?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I developed my vcl app using delphi 10.2 Tokyo and works fine. I want to Implement a scenario whereby it can send notifications in the system notification center or action center whenever there's an action that has taken place. For example if the app is connected, then it should send a notification in the action center that 'connected'. I tried using TNotificationcenter component but it's not compatible with windows 7 but works fine on windows 8 and above.
How do I go about that?
thanks hope this makes sense and I will be grateful to any help rendered.

Comment: You should change the title of this question if possible. Push notifications are not what you are talking about here.

Comment: @DaveNottage enlighten me more about it...thanks

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have notifications. This is an O/S limitation, not a Delphi one.

Comment: @abrahamselous Here is some information about what Push Notifications are: https://buildfire.com/what-is-a-push-notification/

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have notifications or a Notification Center. It's impossible to send notifications when the OS doesn't have any support for them.

Answer (score 0):

Win7 does not have a notification center.  But, you can use a TTrayIcon and Balloon Hint.

```
TrayIcon.BalloonHint := 'My Message';
TrayIconTimer.Enabled := False;
TrayIconTimer.Enabled := True;
TrayIcon.Visible := True;
TrayIcon.ShowBalloonHint;
```

In this example a timer is used to hide the TrayIcon after the balloon timeout.

Works in Win7, in Win10, it looks like a notification, but does not actually get added to the notification center list.